# Selenium [Python Binding, Chrome Driver]: Disable Timeouts Completely

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

We have a Selenium process that fetches data from our data provider for further processing. The process tries to get all historical data, and since we do not have functionality to reliably filter out data that has been edited recently, we must get full data dumps from time to time to ensure that no records are dropped.

The Selenium process is written as a Python script. It goes to a specific website, logs in, presses a button that triggers report generation, and then downloads the report. The issue is that for full dump reports, the report generation has started to take longer than the default Selenium timeouts.

We use the Google Chrome driver, but would be willing to change the browser/driver if only other drivers have the ability to fully disable timeouts.

Below is a simplified, stripped-down version of the code with just the bare bones needed to appropriately describe this issue. The places where the report times out are marked out. It's waiting for a response from the website after clicking a button. How to disable that, and why what we currently do (can be seen below) is not enough?

```
from selenium import webdriver

def selectPopUp(driver, main_window_handle, maxWait=100):
    """
    Selects a pop-up window. If no pop-up window appears, raises an
    Exception.

    :param maxWait: how long to wait (in seconds) before raising the error?
    """

    popup_window_handle = None
    i = 0

    while (not popup_window_handle) and (i < maxWait):

        for handle in driver.window_handles:

            if handle != main_window_handle:
                popup_window_handle = handle
                break

        # Wait a litle and re-iterate.
        time.sleep(1)
        i += 1

    if popup_window_handle != None:
        driver.switch_to.window(popup_window_handle)
        return popup_window_handle
    else:
        raise Exception("No pop-up window appeared although the program was expecting one.")

def selectOption(dropdown, option, possibilities):
    """
    Validates and selects an option from a drop-down.

    :param dropdown: the Selenium reference to the dropdown selection.
    :param option: the name of the option we'll select
    :param possibilities: the possibilities we allow to choose from --
                          will raise an Exception
                          if `option` is not in `possibilities`.
    :returns: Selenium selection.
    """

    # Select the default Excel option
    if option in possibilities:
        return dropdown.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='" + option + "']")\
                       .click()
    else:
        raise Exception("Invalid choice! Use one of the following: \n\n   " + \
                        "\n   ".join(possibilities))


chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=settings.chromeDriver, 
                          chrome_options=chromeOptions)

# Set an infite timeout time so that the slow Crystal reports
# would stand a chance of not timing out too.
driver.set_page_load_timeout(9999999999)
driver.set_script_timeout(9999999999)

# We go to the relevant website - that part is edited out.
# Once in the website, we select the current window handle
# to be able to come back to it after navigating through pop-ups.
main_window_handle = driver.current_window_handle

reportDropDown = driver.find_element_by_id(REPORT_ELEMENT_ID)
selectedReport = reportDropDown.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='" + SELCTED_REPORT_TITLE + "']")
selectedReport.click()

########################################################################
# >>>>>>>> The first place where the process keeps timing out. <<<<<<< #
########################################################################

# Click on the export button to open export pop-up.
exportButton = driver.find_element_by_name(r'crytlViewer$ctl02$ctl00')
exportButton.click()

# Now a pop-up with a download button appears. Select it.
popUpHandle = selectPopUp(driver, main_window_handle)

# Now, select a particular download format.
formatDropDown = driver.find_element_by_id("exportFormatList")
selectedFormat = selectOption(formatDropDown, reportFormat, REPORT_FORMAT_LIST)

# Download the report.
driver.find_element_by_id("submitexport").click()


#########################################################################
# >>>>>>>> The second place where the process keeps timing out. <<<<<<< #
#########################################################################
```

An representative example of an error message we get would be the following.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/core/utils.py", line 296, in repeatUntilSuccess
    return func()
    File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/salesforce/data_feed.py", line 277, in <lambda>
    cleanUp=True),
    File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/salesforce/data_feed.py", line 322, in pushReports
    'liveEnvironment': self.liveEnvironment}]\
    File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/core/reporting.py", line 1160, in __getitem__
    self.handlers[name].PreparePandas(**paramDict)
    File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/reports/vienna_salesforce_data_feed/Salesforce_LoanObject_Parsed.py", line 38, in PreparePandas
    loan = self.manager.handlers[crystalReport].PreparePandas()
    File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/core/reporting.py", line 1231, in PreparePandas
    return self.TransformRaw(self.GetRaw(fileFrom))
    File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/core/reporting.py", line 1387, in GetRaw
    self.PrepareExcel(fileFrom)
    File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/core/reporting.py", line 1367, in PrepareExcel
    fileTo=fileTo)
    File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/vienna/crystal.py", line 293, in downloadReport
    self.downloadReport_no_error_handling(reportTitle, reportFormat, fileTo)
    File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/vienna/crystal.py", line 247, in downloadReport_no_error_handling
    self.driver.find_element_by_id("submitexport").click()
    File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 77, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
    File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    TimeoutException: Message: timeout
    (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.78)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 4.4.0-1052-aws x86_64)
```

After edits suggested by Alexey Dolgopolov, we get the following error message, which is slightly different from the previous one:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/core/utils.py", line 296, in repeatUntilSuccess
  return func()
  File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/salesforce/data_feed.py", line 277, in <lambda>
  cleanUp=True),
  File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/salesforce/data_feed.py", line 322, in pushReports
  'liveEnvironment': self.liveEnvironment}]\
  File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/core/reporting.py", line 1160, in __getitem__
  self.handlers[name].PreparePandas(**paramDict)
  File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/reports/vienna_salesforce_data_feed/Salesforce_LoanObject_Parsed.py", line 38, in PreparePandas
  loan = self.manager.handlers[crystalReport].PreparePandas()
  File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/core/reporting.py", line 1231, in PreparePandas
  return self.TransformRaw(self.GetRaw(fileFrom))
  File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/core/reporting.py", line 1387, in GetRaw
  self.PrepareExcel(fileFrom)
  File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/core/reporting.py", line 1367, in PrepareExcel
  fileTo=fileTo)
  File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/vienna/crystal.py", line 318, in downloadReport
  try:
  File "/home/ubuntu/main/oodle/vienna/crystal.py", line 254, in downloadReport_no_error_handling
  exportButton.click()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 77, in click
  self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
  return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
  self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
  raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
  TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.78)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 4.10.0-26-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: Sorry, I've apparently misunderstood you. Timeout shoots not while finding element but right after clicking. As a result of looooong report generating script. Please look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939451/timeout-when-using-click-webdriver-selenium-function-python. May be it'll help.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. The issue you've provided is related to what we're experiencing,  but their solution doesn't work in our case, it seems. I'm exploring other options, though. I'll post solution here if and when I find one. Until then - all suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `find_element_by_<whatever>` an implicitly_wait timeout plays. The default value is 0.

I guess, you don't need to disable timeouts. Try using Explicit Wait. Read about it  http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html and https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait.

And use something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
...
selectedReport.click()
exportButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 9999, 5).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.NAME, r'crytlViewer$ctl02$ctl00')
        )
```

Comment: Thanks! After your edits, we have a subtly different traceback with the same TimeoutException thrown out. See my edit of the original post for details.

Comment: Alexey - one specific question. After the button click throwing a TimeoutException, is the page continuing to load or does Selenium stop the process entirely? If the page continues to load, we can catch the exception and wait for the page to load.